# Loading a library from an URL versus local

Tags: html

When I load the library from an url, my code works as intended but when I try to load the same library from my local drive it spits out the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: quat is not defined
    at main (main.js:3)
    at onload (index.html?_ijt=h48f9s7rceh7l34tfquh6ab8n5:7)
main @ main.js:3
onload @ index.html?_ijt=h48f9s7rceh7l34tfquh6ab8n5:7
```

What am I doing wrong in second case?

```
//index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body onload="main()">
    <!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.8.1/gl-matrix.js"></script>-->
    <script src="Libraries/gl-matrix.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

//main.js
function main()
{
    let x = quat.create();
    console.log(x);
}
```

Comment: I just copy/pasted your code to local files and run them. `x` was logged successfully and the error you reported did not appear. I can't reproduce your problem with the code you provided.

Comment: this code with url works but I want this to work only with local. I mean this code spits error when I comment url part and uncomment local loading part. I do not understand why. I am providing it with the same local file.

Comment: Then the most likely reason is that `main.js` is the wrong URL, but there's no way to test that from here.

Comment: if it was the case it would not work with the remote url case too.

Comment: Why would `main.js` being the wrong URL make `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.8.1/gl-matrix.js` the wrong URL? I can load `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.8.1/gl-matrix.js` and clearly see that it is a JS file.

Comment: https://i.hizliresim.com/ZXkEPk.png            this is my structure. Using Webstorm by the way.

Answer (score -1):

Your main.js file is loading before the main plugin script loading change the order like this.

```
<script src="Libraries/gl-matrix.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: That doesn't matter since `quat` isn't accessed until `main()` is called which doesn't happen until the `load` event fires.

Answer (score -1):

first, please try changing the order of your `<script>` tags. Try loading the `gl-matrix.js` file first. Additionally you should make sure to provide either an absolute path to your local `gl-matrix.js` file or a path relative to the location of the file your `<body>`tags are located in.

Best Regards,
Bachkippe

Comment: The order doesn't matter since `quat` isn't accessed until `main()` is called which doesn't happen until the `load` event fires.

Comment: The local gl-matrix file isn't loaded at all, the script elements are commented out. The library is loaded from a CDN.